# Using an "if not x" statement in an HBS template file

Tags: handlebars.js

How can I write an `if not x` statement in an HBS template file?

At present, I use an `if/else` clause in order to achieve that:

```
{{#if x}}
{{else}}
Some Text
{{/if}}
```

Is there a way to simplify this and use a single `if` statement?

I've tried stuff like `{{#if !x}}` and `{{#if ^x}}`, but it didn't work of course.

Looking on the web for HBS logical operators, I couldn't quite find the syntax for a *logical-not*.

### Update

I should emphasize that in my case `x` is `undefined`.

I've learned it "the hard way", while trying:

```
{{#if not x}}
Some Text
{{/if}}
```

Which threw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'includeZero' of undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `unless`?

```
<div class="entry">
  {{#unless license}}
  <h3 class="warning">WARNING: This entry does not have a license!</h3>
  {{/unless}}
</div>
```

> You can use the unless helper as the inverse of the if helper. Its
>   block will be rendered if the expression returns a falsy value.

https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also considers custom helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("ifNot", function(a, options){
    if (!a) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }else{
        try{
            return options.inverse(this);
        }catch(e){
           //no else statement
        }
    }
});
```